# Collection find method doesn't work on Angular 2 recursive function

Tags: mongodb, angular, meteor, recursion

I'm developing Angular2 with Meteor.

When I make a little component with a recursive function, it has some weird error.

Here is my part of codes.

**Not recursive - return a result**

```
ngOnInit() {
        //this.current_canvas return the right results
        this.current_canvas = this.get_canvase(1);
}
get_canvase(which_canvas): Canvas[] {
    if (!isNaN(which_canvas)) {
        this.current_canvas_id = which_canvas;
        return CanvasContents.find().map((messages: Canvas[]) => { return messages; })[0].content;
        return '';
    } else if(which_canvas == 'most-recent') {
        this.get_canvase(1);
    }
}
```

**Recursive - Don't return a result**

```
ngOnInit() {
        //this.current_canvas Goes to NUll
        this.current_canvas = this.get_canvase('most-recent');
}
get_canvase(which_canvas): Canvas[] {
    if (!isNaN(which_canvas)) {
        this.current_canvas_id = which_canvas;
        console.log('this.current_canvas_id : ' + this.current_canvas_id);
        return CanvasContents.find().map((messages: Canvas[]) => { return messages; })[0].content;
        return '';
    } else if(which_canvas == 'most-recent') {
        this.get_canvase(1);
    }
}
```

Have I used a wrong syntax? or is it on wrong Angular2 state to get right result?

Comment: What error do you get? You have 2 `return` in first if branch, and none in second.

Comment: My error is that second one doesn't return a result when I using `this.current_canvas = this.get_canvase('most-recent');` this line to get `this.current_canvas`.